# Annotate equation

Tags: equations

I have an equation that uses (\varphi) which I'd like to define with a text, like the following (hardcoded) example:

[image]

The "traditional" way would be to do this in the surrounding text:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\textbf{Textbased}

Blabla where $\varphi$ is \texttt{definition}

\begin{equation}
\varphi = 1337
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Now, doing a simple `\text{def}` would work, however this affects the alignment, as the equation is centered around the *total* equation, which includes the `\text{def}`. Furthermore, the definition is not right-aligned as desired:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\textbf{Quadbased}

\begin{equation}
\varphi = 1337 \qquad \text{defs}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Another option is listing a tag. This does what I desire, which is to define some variable to the side of the main equation. However, its main problem is that it actually replaces the equation number like so:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\textbf{Tagbased}

\begin{equation}
\varphi = 1337 \tag*{defs}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Anyone that has a solution?

Answer (score 15):

Welcome! You could use `\newtagform` from `mathtools`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newtagform{defs}{\text{defs}~(}{)}
\begin{document}
\usetagform{defs}
\begin{equation}
\varphi = 1337
\end{equation}
\usetagform{default}
\begin{equation}
E=m\,c^2
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As illustrated, with `\usetagform{default}` you can switch back to the default tag form.